# Android EditText OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, input, focus, android-edittext

does anyone know if there is possible to clean OnFocusChangeListener from EditText?

My situation is something like that:

1. I set OnFocusChangeListener for EditText
2. After a while I need to change its behavior, but calling setOnFocusChangeListener for second time has no affect

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you show some code of how you do it? New `OnFocusChangeListener` should replace previous one.

Comment: e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    // my actions 1
});

and later 

e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    // my actions 2
});

Comment: That should work. :-) But this code doesn't help really. You should show a part of your code, a whole class or something. And by the way - you might consider editing your question instead of putting code in comments. Would be more clear for other readers.

Comment: @Toochka don't add it to the comment. update your question with more code. the code in comment is not sufficient. So that new users get rid of going through the comments to find the question

Comment: I know that's rude of me, but I cannot post lots of code. For now as I see, the setOnFocusChangeListener has no affect when is being called for the second+ time.

Comment: @Toochka : I have same issue as yours. Now You can find out what's wrong? Please tell me solution. Thanks